# Java EE 6 and Singletons

Tags: java, annotations, singleton, java-ee-6

Can anyone explain the full process of implementing a Singleton in a Java EE 6 app? I'm assuming that I shouldn't be creating a singleton in the typical way of declaring a static variable and should be using the `@Singleton` annotation? Do I have to do it this way?

Is it just a case of declaring it `@Singleton` and that's it? Do I have to do anymore to the class?

What do I then need to do to access the singleton in my other classes?

Answer (score 9):

> *Is it just a case of declaring it @Singleton and that's it?*

Yes! That's it! Just design the class like any other Javabean.

Do however note that this is indeed not the same as GoF's [Singleton design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). Instead, it's exactly the ["just create one" pattern](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.SingletonVsJustCreateOne). Perhaps that's the source of your confusion. Admittedly, the annotation name is somewhat poorly chosen, in JSF and CDI the name `@ApplicationScoped` is been used.

---

> *What do I then need to do to access the singleton in my other classes?*

Just the same way as every other EJB, by injecting it as `@EJB`:

```
@EJB
private YourEJB yourEJB;
```

Answer (score 3):

The `javax.ejb.Singleton` annotation is used to specify that the enterprise bean implementation class is a singleton session bean.

This information is to tell the ejb container, not to create multiple instance of this bean and only create a singleton instance. Otherwise it is just a normal bean class. Read more here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipvi.html

You don't have to create a static variable, and do all the related stuff to make it singleton. Just write a normal bean as mentioned here and container will take care of instantiating only object of it:

```
@Startup
@Singleton
public class StatusBean {
  private String status;

  @PostConstruct
  void init {
    status = "Ready";
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: This still doesn't really answer my first question, is it really needed?

Comment: @Sly updated my answer. You just have to create a normal bean, without any singleton, static variable, prviate constructor and related stuff.